# Issue with using org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2 Java SDK while migrating from Spring 5 to Spring 6

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We plan to migrate to Spring 6 from Spring 5 and were using `spring-security-oauth2:2.5.1` library.

Now with Spring 6, since we need to use Jakarta namespace and `spring-security-oauth2` latest 2.5.2 maven dependency still uses `javax` namespace internally, we are kind of stuck.

Comment: Spring Security OAuth2 reached end of life last year. OAuth2 support was added with Spring Security 5. So you have to migrate your Spring Security configuration and remove also Spring Security OAuth2 dependency.